# GCP Error when performing Stackdriver AsyncReporter health check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

My application runs in the following error when trying to perform Stackdriver AsyncReporter health check. I can't seem to find which authentication scopes are required for this from the documentation.

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    at zipkin2.reporter.stackdriver.internal.AwaitableUnaryClientCallListener.onClose(AwaitableUnaryClientCallListener.java:100)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:562)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:743)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:722)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Currently, my application is using the following authentication scopes

```
Scopes in use by default credentials: 

[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub,
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin,
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append,
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery,
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
```

Answer (score 0):

The prerequisites required for a service account to call the api  are

1. Select or create a Cloud Platform project.
2. Enable the StackdriverLogging API.
3. Set up [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) with a service account so you can
   access the API.
4. Check whether your service account is allowed to create.

The Stackdriver Logging APIs prohibit requests made with only an API key and require requests to be authenticated (OAuth2). The [Cloud IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control) that are needed must be granted to the requesting user. Because they typically access or modify resources that are protected by IAM, the majority of Google Cloud APIs function in this manner. Additionally, there is no "principal" to grant access to if the request only makes use of an API key.

Attaching supporting [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-deny) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, resolution was to add
`Cloud Trace API` write privileges to service account used for running application (cloud run in my case).